# Why do you use the keyword delete?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory

I understand that delete returns memory to the heap that was allocated of the heap, but what is the point? Computers have plenty of memory don't they? And all of the memory is returned as soon as you "X" out of the program.

Comment: This should be tagged as a bad joke.

Comment: Probably just a student trying to throw one of our quotes in his teacher's face after he got a bad mark on a test for not cleaning up his memory..

Comment: Answer the question, and be polite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

Consider a server that allocates an object `Packet` for each packet it receives (this is bad design for the sake of the example).
A server, by nature, is intended to *never* shut down. If you never `delete` the thousands of `Packet` your server handles per second, your system is going to swamp and crash in a few minutes.

Another example:

Consider a video game that allocates particles for the special effect, everytime a new explosion is created (and never deletes them). In a game like Starcraft (or other recent ones), after a few minutes of hilarity and destruction (and hundres of thousands of particles), lag will be so huge that your game will turn into a PowerPoint slideshow, effectively making your player unhappy.

Answer (score 2):

Not all programs exit quickly.

Some applications may run for hours, days or longer. Daemons may be designed to run without cease. Programs can easily consume more memory over their lifetime than available on the machine.

In addition, not all programs run in isolation. Most need to share resources with other applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons why you should manage your memory usage, as well as any other computer resources you use:

- What might start off as a lightweight program could soon become more complex, depending on your design areas of memory consumption may grow exponentially.
- Remember you are sharing memory resources with other programs. Being a good neighbour allows other processes to use the memory you free up, and helps to keep the entire system stable.
- You don't know how long your program might run for. Some people hibernate their session (or never shut their computer down) and might keep your program running for years.

There are many other reasons, I suggest researching on memory allocation for more details on the do's and don'ts.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point, what computers have lots of memory but you are wrong. As an engineer you have to create programs, what uses computer resources properly.

Imagine, you made program which runs all the time then computer is on. It sometimes creates some objects/variables with "new". After some time you don't need them anymore and you don't delete them. Such a situation occurs time to time and you just make some RAM out of stock. After a while user have to terminate your program and launch it again. It is not so bad but it not so comfortable, what is more, your program may be loading for a while. Because of these user feels bad of your silly decision.

Another thing. Then you use "new" to create object you call constructor and "delete" calls destructor. Lets say you need to open so file and destructor closes it and makes it accessible for other processes in this case you would steel not only memory but also files from other processes.

If you don't want to use "delete" you can use shared pointers (it has garbage collector).
It can be found in STL, std::shared_ptr, it has one disatvantage, WIN XP SP 2 and older do not support this. So if you want to create something for public you should use boost it also has boost::shared_ptr. To use boost you need to download it from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) and configure your development environment to use it.